# Leverage browser caching for youtube thumbnails

Tags: youtube-api, browser-cache, youtube-javascript-api, pagespeed, http-caching

I am using Youtube (v3)API for my website where many youtube video thumbnails are displayed.
For example something like: https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/0ZL_q7oUVrQ/mqdefault.jpg

When I check the Google Insights(https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) for my website it complains about bad 'Leverage browser caching'. I had already taken care by adding expiry date for static resources coming from my server like js/css files but Google insights is mainly complaining about thumbnail images which are coming externally, direct from Youtube servers.

My website has many of these thumbnails and caching them is very important for fast page loads but youtube servers have set the expiry time for only 6 hours and I do not find a way to change that since they are external to my servers.

I would be very thankful if someone can suggest me of any better way to take care of browser caching for my usecase where resources are coming from external servers(like in my case thumbnails from youtube servers) 
I am surprised that Youtube sets the expiry for only 6 hours though images are the least possible resources to change often...!

Answer (score 0):

It's outside of your control so I don't think you can do anything about it.

These are your options:

- Cache/update cache yourself.
- Get the remote admin to change it (not possible with youtube).
- Ignore.